# MySQL match against multiple values

Tags: mysql

I've got the following table:

```
nid | tag_id
--------------
1   | 213
1   | 78
2   | 938
2   | 1002
2   | 8573
2   | 5
3   | 3957
3   | 487
4   | 56
```

I want to retreive a single nid where tag_id matches several values say 1002,938,8573.

I started with the following query:

```
SELECT nid,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag_id ORDER BY tag_id) tag_ids FROM table GROUP BY nid
```

which returns:

```
nid | tag_ids
--------------
1   | 78,213
2   | 5,938,1002,8573
3   | 487,3957
4   | 56
```

But I haven't found anything yet that'll will allow me to match the tag_ids column again my set of values.  I need it to match all not just anyone of the values.

Maybe my approach is wrong so happy to look at different methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you are building your query in some sort of application code, you could use

```
SELECT nid
FROM table
WHERE tag_id IN (tag1, tag2, tag3, ...)
GROUP BY nid
HAVING COUNT(*) = n;
```

where n is the number of tags in your list. This should find all nids which match your entire tag list.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause will give you what you want.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I could use the having clause to match several values.. could you provide me with an eg?

Comment: This "hint" should have been a comment under the question.

Comment: You are ten years too late.  Perhaps you should use your time here more productively.